# Gradle group clean build as one task does not work

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build, jar

I am working on a multi-module project using gradle composite build
I have something like this

Project A is a lib jar

Project B is another lib jar but uses project A

Project C is the service app using project A and B

I used included build and dependency linked them as the relationship above and they all can do `./gradlew clean build` in side the module directory

When I create a composite build outside of these 3 project and in the root directory I created tasks as below.

```
tasks.register("cleanAll") {
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("A").task(":clean"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("B").task(":clean"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("C").task(":clean"))
}

tasks.register("buildAll") {
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("A").task(":build"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("B").task(":build"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("C").task(":build"))
}

tasks.register("cleanBuildAll") {
    // Style 1
    dependsOn(tasks.getByName("cleanAll"))
    dependsOn(tasks.getByName("buildAll"))
    // Style 2
    // dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("A").task(":clean"))
    // dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("B").task(":clean"))
    // dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("C").task(":clean"))
    // dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("A").task(":build"))
    // dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("B").task(":build"))
    // dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("C").task(":build"))
}
```

While running `./gradlew cleanAll` and `./gradlew buildAll` in sequence, there is no problem at all, all project builds fine.
But if I run `./gradlew cleanBuildAll` it fails and gives me an error like this, both `Style 1` and `Style 2` gives me the same error.

```
Execution failed for task ':C:kaptTestKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':C:detachedConfiguration2'.
   > Failed to transform A.jar to match attributes {artifactType=class-structure, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for StructureTransformAction: <root_project_path>/libs/A/build/libs/Ajar.
         > <root_project_path>libs/A/build/libs/A.jar
```

Any idea why the clean and build task cannot be grouped into one task? Thank you.

**Edit:** I also notice something interesting. I created tasks like below, when I first run it, it executed 5 out of 37(5/37) tasks. and the unit tests were not run, when I run it again, it executed 37/37 and unit tests are run. If I keep running it, its all giving me 37/37 tasks. Not sure if this is related. And what is the reason behind this?

```
tasks.register("buildA") {
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("A").task(":clean"))
    dependsOn(gradle.includedBuild("A").task(":build"))
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Gradle is not Maven, so calling `clean` isn't really necessary as it has proper input/output tracking to know what needs rebuilding.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but you can use `gradle.includedBuilds.map { it.task(":clean") }` to avoid listing each of your included builds. And regarding the question: I guess using `dependsOn` alone doesn't state anything on the order at which each of dependency tasks is executed - maybe this is the reason? Did you try something like `mustRunAfter` or `shouldRunAfter`?